# How do I grab the end of a letter and strech it along a curved path to join it to another letter?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to stretch the end of a letter and join it to another letter. I would like to have a consistent arch between one letter and another. Lets say a "W" and a "L" for example.

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried and possibly a sketch of what you want to achieve? A picture is worth more than a 1,000 words.

Comment: There are **many** ways you may be able to accomplish this. Without more specifics, and some indication regarding what you've attempted, it's really impossible to write a 40 page manual on all the possible methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to imitate ligatures between letters, but make them manually editable, you can turn your text to outlines and tweak them however you'd like.